# Are WinRT Metro apps cross-compatible (x86/64 and ARM)?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

The Wikipedia entry about Windows 8 claims in its [Metro section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8#Metro-style_applications) that

> Metro applications will be cross-compatible with both x86/64 based
>   systems and Windows on ARM.

but does not have a reference (it is marked with "citation needed").

Technically, would it be possible to run a "native" Metro app which was build using WinRT for x86/64 on ARM?

Comment: I'm sure that if you write your code in JavaScript or use .NET and compile for AnyCPU, they will be portable across architectures. If you compile for x86, though, you won't be able to run on ARM.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Metro apps are specifically stated as the supported method for doing cross platform apps on both Windows 8 and WOA (Windows on ARM). Full details are in [this blog post.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/02/09/building-windows-for-the-arm-processor-architecture.aspx) The post also states that other types of applications that run in Desktop mode in x86 Windows 8 are specifically not supported on WOA (some Microsoft apps being the sole exceptions).

Answer (score 2):

A JS app should work on ARM unmodified. I'm not 100% sure about C#, an app written for "any CPU" **should** just work on ARM (but I've not confirmed).  C++ applications will work, but will need to be recompiled specially for ARM.

Comment: It makes me very nervous that •you• don't know what the story is for .net developers

Comment: @RobertLevy: I am being *VERY* conservative when I answer on SO.  I don't have an ARM machine, so I don't know the answer to the question.  I *think* it should work, but without an ARM machine to check, I can't confirm.  From the way that JS is architected, I know it should work (although you'll note that I still hedged my bet in my answer).

Comment: .NET works transparently on ARM, although "unsafe" code and "Pinvoke"s can cause problems. In the case of WinRT, unsafe and Pinvokes are banned, and .NET apps pushed through the Win8 appstore will have to be compiled /pure:CLR and /M:AnyCPU, so yes, WinRT.NET will work on WOA.