# develop metro style apps for Intel based processors and ARM based processors

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, arm, c#-5.0, conditional-compilation

I want to ask if there are any differences when I develop metro style apps for Intel based processors devices or for ARM based processors ?

Are there limitations in code? Or do some APIs not work? Or can I write only one Windows 8 metro style app and run it on *both*?

Comment: I disagree with the close reason for this question since I think it's a valid question, however, it is a dupe of for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654609/are-winrt-metro-apps-cross-compatible-x86-64-and-arm?rq=1 which has some answer which might be useful for you to read.

Comment: Thanks for your appreciated help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using C#, you can compile for both platforms without jumping through any special hoops. Only if you use libraries with specialized platform-dependent code (which aren't that many nowadays) you need to be careful.

In the API, I haven't come across functions that were restricted to one of the platforms either.